# How to make dynamic response clock in android?

Tags: android, clock

So im working on a app and i need to make a circle (clock) that when i move clock indicators changes some values. 
The idea is when i move the indicator with a finger the clock changes.

There is an example in the link bellow:

[Example here](https://i.gyazo.com/96f8faa3cbebaa742daac4e82ea74b8f.png)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood question correctly, you can use library like this https://github.com/bozapro/circular-slider-range . To actually update some TextView inside clock circle you can use something like:

```
((CrystalRangeSeekbar) findViewById(R.id.range_slider)).setOnRangeSeekbarChangeListener(new OnRangeSeekbarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(Number minValue, Number maxValue) {
                //Your code to change TextViews here
            }
        });
```